# Interpreting The Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Given the usual setup, the weak law of large numbers states that for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(|M_n - \mu| > \epsilon) = 0
$$

According to [this](http://ravi-bhide.blogspot.com/2012/06/on-weak-law-and-strong-law-of-large.html) author, the interpretation is as follows:

> (1) For large values of $n$, (i.e. $n \ge N$ for some $N$) the
>   probability that the value of $M_n$ (the sample mean) differs from the
>   population mean $\mu$ by more than any given number $\epsilon > 0$
>   is 0.
>
> (2) Alternatively, all probability is concentrated in an $\epsilon$
>   interval around $\mu$.
>
> (3) Alternatively, almost surely, for large samples, the sample mean is
>   within an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the population mean.

I understand all of this, but am having trouble reconciling this interpretation with the following statement from *Exploring Monte Carlo Methods* by Dunn and Shultis, which states (notation adapted slightly)

> The weak form of the law of large numbers states that, for a specified
>   large $N$, the sample mean $M_N$ is likely to be near $\mu$. But
>   it leaves open the possibility that cases when $|M_N - \mu|
> > \epsilon$, i.e. when the deviation of $M_N$ from $\mu$ is
>   outside some small tolerance interval $\epsilon$, can occur an
>   arbitrary (even infinite) number of times as $N$ increases; however
>   such occurrences happen at infrequent intervals.

Is there a contradiction between these two interpretations?

The first author is saying that for all $n \ge N$, with probability 1, the sample mean is within $\epsilon$ of $\mu$, but the second author says that for $n > N$ the weak law leaves open the possibility we have an infinite number of deviations larger than $\epsilon$. But if this happens an infinite number of times, how can the event occur **almost surely**?

Comment: I think (1) is not correct, It should be (1) For large values of $n$, (i.e. $n≥n_0$ for some $n_0$) the limit of probability that the value of $M_n$ (the sample mean) differs from the population mean $μ$ by more than any given number $ϵ>0$ is 0.

Comment: Now it is OK and there is no contradiction here.

Comment: @jesterII the integers are infinite in number and yet the Lebesgue measure of $Z$ is $0$.

Comment: The precise statement of (1) would be that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $P(|M_n - \mu| > \delta)<\epsilon$. To be clear, one can certainly have a large deviation from the mean, so $M_n$ can land outside $(\mu-\delta,\mu+\delta)$. The WLLN tells you this occurs with low probability. You can read more about it here http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/LLN.html ; the link also contains useful applets and experiments to give you further intuition.

Comment: The first author is not giving precise statements and/or is mixing "weak law" and "strong law" statements. The second author is giving a more precise statement of the weak law.  The possibility that deviation an infinite number of times is not ruled out, which the second author correctly talks about,  does not actually happen because there is also a strong law that can be proven.  However, there are examples of sequences $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $X_n$ converges to 0 in probability, but $X_n=1$ for an infinite number of indices $n$ (so it does not converge to 0 with probability 1).

Comment: In short, it is not possible to use language of "almost surely" when discussing the weak law. That language is reserved only for the strong law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We say $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$ "in probability" if for all $\epsilon>0$: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr[|X_n-0|>\epsilon] = 0 $$

We say $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$ "with probability 1" if for all $\epsilon>0$: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr\left[\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+1}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+2}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\cdots\right] = 0 $$

Of course: 
$$\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\} \subseteq \{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+1}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+2}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\cdots $$
Thus: 
$$ Pr[|X_n-0|>\epsilon] \leq Pr\left[\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+1}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+2}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\cdots\right] $$
and so: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr[|X_n-0|>\epsilon] \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr\left[\{|X_n-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+1}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_{n+2}-0|>\epsilon\}\cup\cdots\right] $$

You can see that it is easier for the left-hand-side to converge to $0$ than the right-hand-side to converge to $0$. So "convergence with probability 1" implies "convergence in probability," but not vice versa. A standard example to show the reverse does not necessarily hold is this:

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of mutually independent random variables such that:

$$ X_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ with probability $(n-1)/n$} \\
1  & \mbox{ with probability $1/n$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Then $X_n$ converges to $0$ "in probability" because for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $Pr[|X_n-0|>\epsilon] = 1/n$, and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Pr[|X_n-0|>\epsilon] = 0$.

However, it turns out that (with probability 1) we have $X_n=1$ for an *infinite number* of indices $n$, so $X_n$ certainly does not converge to $0$ with probability 1.  To understand why, fix any arbitrarily large positive integer $M$ and compute the probability that $X_n=0$ for all $n\geq M$:

$$ Pr\left[\cap_{n\geq M} \{X_n=0\}\right] = \prod_{n=M}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = 0 $$

The intuition is that, regardless of how large $M$ is, there will (with probability 1) be another index $n$ even larger such that $X_n=1$ (of course, it may take a long time to get there).  Once that occurs, there will again (with probability 1) be an even larger index such that it happens again. And then again, and again, and so on.